# Reset SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, methods, settings, sharedpreferences, reset

I used the method in ShredPreferences, this way I saved my app-settind,
But I have a question. 
Is it possible to Reset my saved settings, and come back to default value?
The code that I'm using saves the changes of ImageButton's image. I would like to reset settings and restore default value after a click of a specific Reset-Button.

Thanks for everything!

```
private static final String Mypref= "pref";

final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Mypref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
buttonClick1.setImageResource(pref.getInt(Mypref, R.drawable.default_value));
image.setImageResource(imageResource);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putInt("Mypref", R.drawable.users_value_chosen);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply remove (clear) shared preferences. Then, when you read them, just provide default values in the code.

```
pref.edit().clear().commit();
```

The next line will use R.drawable.default_value as a default value, because preferences were deleted.

Comment: Very Helpful, one question beworker, I have to clese my code with:
editor.commit(); or It's not important??
 kind regards!

Comment: You should always call commit() after changing settings. It will save changes to the internal flash storage. Otherwise your changes stay in  memory only.

Answer (score 3):

By using clear() method we can reset shared preference values.

```
private static final String Mypref= "pref";  
final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Mypref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();  
editor.clear().commit();
```